# Issues with Boostrap grid, overflow scroll, and responsive layout when using defined heights (vh) in elements

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a two column layout using Boostrap 4 that uses an overflow scroll when I set the height of a parent container.

Here is a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zeropsi/g19kzpsh/

The issue that I am having is that using a set height for the `.section` does not actually set the height for the column, and the overflow scroll is not working correctly.

Any ideas on how I can get the two columns to work, with the left column having a scroll for any overflow content that reaches past the height of the parent containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right. The problem is happening because of how and where the height was set. These are the changes made:

```
.section {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 75vh !important; */
  float: left;
}

.test{
  width:auto;
  height:75vh !important;
}
```

[JS fiddle answer](https://jsfiddle.net/8bh5o76f/1/)